Why is there "nft":null in Opensea API's cancel event type?
I am having some issues fully understanding the cancel event type from Opensea API endpoint - https://docs.opensea.io/reference/list_events_by_collection.
One example output is
{
  "event_type": "cancel",
  "order_hash": "0xab4a94ced0d0b2f5724abb7c30995f15bf47db8f369e42925331ab9f2c2124f2",
  "order_type": "listing",
  "maker": "0xb756a8a4e0c827a7ddb151085c26fc11717cfc1b",
  "chain": "ethereum",
  "event_timestamp": 1726107065,
  "nft": {
    "identifier": "7191",
    "collection": "official-v1-punks",
    "contract": "0x282bdd42f4eb70e7a9d9f40c8fea0825b7f68c5d",
    "token_standard": "erc721",
    "name": "V1 PUNK #7191",
    "description": "CryptoPunks were released & free to claim in 2017, but were not safely tradable. This modern wrapper allows Punks to be traded on current NFT marketplaces.\n\nCryptoPunks have a transparent background for visualization of their current status, the lavender background designates the Punk has been safely wrapped.\n\nThe recovery of the original Punks smart contract is a community driven project.",
    "image_url": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQxJWSh1WVgvMHzpNvZsiy736Rtve3udcDnbeMk84zFZr",
    "display_image_url": "https://i.seadn.io/s/raw/files/6a54fa873998a6bcae63f2d352faa974.png?w=500&auto=format",
    "display_animation_url": null,
    "metadata_url": "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmcsX1EprrBwjPRT7dyDWvmGX7zvcRsmKKDaMTiFbSsZh2/7191",
    "opensea_url": "https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x282bdd42f4eb70e7a9d9f40c8fea0825b7f68c5d/7191",
    "updated_at": "2024-08-23T16:10:18.773481",
    "is_disabled": false,
    "is_nsfw": false
  }
}

However, there are other cancel of listing that doesn't specify a collection and token id, such as {"event_type": "cancel", "order_hash": "0xd1d4d5d5b5978a00902969e1117a987f90b7f7f8ec5d759f81c40dc51406342d", "order_type": "listing", "maker": "0xbd0b24fb974c074544a32ca36bc0e3d97bca6311", "chain": "ethereum", "event_timestamp": 1726107051, "nft": null}
Why is that? And what kind of listing will this cancel?
